# CSS classes autocomplete not working with web-mode

Tags: spacemacs, web-mode, ctags

I'm struggling with a problem with Spacemacs and I don't know what I'm doing wrong (maybe a lot of things).

I have created a TAG file for my project. The tags seem to work well because I can navigate to the definition or find the tag with `find-tag`.

The problem is CSS autocomplete popup it's not showing. So when I'm editing an HTML file, I have not autocompletion for CSS classes. I can use helm complete at point, though.

For clarification, I want a popup similar to this:

[image]

I have tried to follow the advice on [this blog post](http://blog.binchen.org/posts/code-completion-for-htmljscss-in-emacs.html) but without results.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I was making some tests, and I have been able to prove that the problem is that `company-gtags` is not enabled within a string (a class element for example). Instead I have tried `company-etags` and if I start the backend manually with `company-beging-backend`, I can see the pop up with the CSS classes. As far I can see [in this github PR](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/commit/250ca1c395c6f05b733abce69a2d928b6cd31618) `company-etags` has an option to enable code completion on strings. But I don't know how to add it to my .spacemas. I have tried into user-config and user-init but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can finally solve my problem.

I have added this lines to `user-init`:

```
  (with-eval-after-load 'company-etags '(progn (add-to-list 'company-etags-modes 'web-mode)))
  (setq company-etags-everywhere '(html-mode web-mode nxml-mode))
```

But also it's necessary to add the `company-etags` backend to `web-mode` so I have also append this line to `user-config`:

```
 (push '(company-web-html company-etags company-css) company-backends-web-mode)
```